# Showing a tooltip on a chart mousemove event blocks other events in C#

Tags: c#, charts

I have a chart where I'm displaying a tooltip whenever the mouse hints a point. It works perfectly using the mousemove event. However, when the tooltip is displayed, other events such as mouse_click are blockeds. I want to be able to let the user click even if the tooltip is displayed.

[image]

```
private void chartPRX_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
/******/
tooltip.Show(" Temps=" + DateTime.FromOADate(prop.XValue).ToString("H:mm:ss") + ", PAM=" + prop.YValues[0].ToString("f2"),
                                            this.chartPAM, pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
/*****/
}

private void chartPRX_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   /*** This code is never executed while the tooltip is displayed ****/
}
```

Comment: need more code to make conclusion. but it looks like your clicks went on the tooltip frame and thus not captured b your chart

Comment: @Steve is there a way to disable the event ? so it can no longer be activated.

Comment: you would need to move your tooltip position if my guess is right. not disable the event

Comment: @Steve That's it, I just moved the tooltip and now it's working correctly. Thanks.